# How To Change TextBox DateTime Display Format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

how can I change format on a date in textbox.Now its display dd/MM/yyyy. Date comes from DateTimePicker.I try to change date format in jQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.datepicker.defaults.language = 'bg';
        $('#NewsDate').addClass("date-picker");
        $('.date-picker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
        });
    });
```

after this DateFormat in viewmodel:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Задължително поле")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime NewsDate { get; set; }
```

but again nothing.I dont have any idea what can i do more.Here is my code in the view;

Дата на новина:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewsDate, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "Избери дата от 1900-2099", pattern = @"^((0|1|2|3)\d{1})/((0|1)\d{1})/((19|20)\d{2})" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Do you need a `DateTime` type? If you're just displaying the date then it's often better to have a `string` in the view model. The conversion from date in the db to string is done when you map the view model to the context object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the bootstrap-datepicker instead of **dateFormat** you should use **format** that means it should be **format: "MM/dd/yyyy"**. And to viewmodel please add this **[DataType(DataType.Date)]** below Required.